# Как сделать ввод символа в TextBox с помощью клика по Button?

Tags: windows, c++

Нужно чтобы в TextBox по клику вписывался символ и при каждом следующем клике этот символ добавлялся. Сначала думал сделать цикл и прибавление символа к имеющемуся, но думаю есть более простой способ. Подскажите пожалуйста. MSDN пересмотрел и ничего подобного не нашел. Может плохо искал...

Answer (score 1):

Навесить обработчик клика на кнопку и в нем присвоить значение текстовому полю (это если вы .NET используете)

```
private void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.Text += "X";
}
```

Comment: спасибо :) (ваще не подумал что можно складывать) с++
получилось так:
textBox1.Text += "X";